# How to count the number of changed lines in monaco diff editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, diff, monaco-editor

I want to count the changed lines in monaco diff editor. Something how that looks like in "Github" where is visible how many lines are added or deleted.
For example, in the [Navigating a Diff playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-diffeditor-navigating-a-diff),
I want to show that 2 lines are deleted, and 2 lines added.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to access the [`IDiffEditor`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.IDiffEditor.html) function [`getLineChanges`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.IDiffEditor.html#getLineChanges)

```js
// It will get all the changes including adds/removals and modified
diffEditor.getLineChanges();
```

The result will be an array of [`ILineChange`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ILineChange.html):

```
[{
    charChanges: undefined
    modifiedEndLineNumber: 0
    modifiedStartLineNumber: 1
    originalEndLineNumber: 2
    originalStartLineNumber: 2
}, [{
    modifiedEndColumn: 5
    modifiedEndLineNumber: 7
    modifiedStartColumn: 1
    modifiedStartLineNumber: 7
    originalEndColumn: 0
    originalEndLineNumber: 0
    originalStartColumn: 0
    originalStartLineNumber: 0
}]]
```

Then you will need to iterate over them to get a resume of them analyzing the array and sub objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little snippet of something that worked for me when looking for total editor lines in an inline diff.

```js
const changes = diffEditor.getLineChanges();

const diffLines = changes.reduce((sum, diff) => {
    let changedLines = sum.changed;
    // Get modified changes
    if (diff.modifiedStartLineNumber && diff.modifiedEndLineNumber) {
        changedLines += diff.modifiedEndLineNumber - diff.modifiedStartLineNumber + 1;
    }
            // Get modified changes
    if (diff.originalEndLineNumber && diff.originalStartLineNumber) {
        changedLines += diff.originalEndLineNumber - diff.originalStartLineNumber + 1;
    }

            // Min will tell us where the diff started
    const minLineNum = Math.min(diff.originalStartLineNumber, diff.modifiedStartLineNumber)
            // Max tells us which line number we end on
    const maxLineNum = Math.max(diff.originalEndLineNumber, diff.modifiedEndLineNumber)

            // This accounts for common lines prior to where this diff started
    changedLines += minLineNum - sum.headPtr;

    return { changed: changedLines, headPtr: maxLineNum };
}, {changed: 0, headPtr: 0});

    // There could be more lines in common after the final "change" so add those here
const totalLines = diffLines.changed + Math.max(originalModel.getLineCount(), modifiedModel.getLineCount()) - diffLines.headPtr;
```